# How can I find description details of services/processes running in Linux?

Tags: linux

If I run the command `ps aux` or `pstree` I get a list of services, processes or applications. For example, I have an application (am unsure if it is a process or a service) called wnck-applet listed when I run the command `pstree`. I run the command `apt-cache showpkg` however it does not list wnck-applet as an available package. How can I lookup the description of a particular service, process or application without having to resort to the web? I attempted a search for wnck-applet however it did not yield a result that explains what it is.

**EDIT**

The current distributions of use at the moment are Debian and Linux Mint.

Comment: Which operating system? (I mean "Debian", "Gentoo", "Ubuntu" and such, not "Linux" which is overly broad). I see that it is APT based and thus probably related to Debian in some way, but others might not know.

Comment: @Daniel Andersson - I apologize. I have include the additional details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a system using APT (which it seems to be), you can use **`apt-file`** like this:

```
apt-file search wnck-applet
```

to get information on which package the binary is related to and then you can e.g.

- look at the package documentation in `/usr/share/docs` if it exists,
- look for man pages (and extended info pages where applicable) if they exist,
- open the executable file in a text editor to see if it is text based, or
- try `-h` or `--h`

in descending order. Not all steps are applicable in every case. In these times the web is often a preferred shortcut if one has the possibility, though.

`apt-file` gives me that `wnck-applet` turns out to be related to `gnome-panel`. More documentation could then be hunted with that new information.

[The Debian manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-search.en.html#s-apt-file) indicates that `apt-file` is the best way. It also mentions **`dpkg -S`** which works similarly, but only on installed packages (which is OK in this case, but `apt-file` has a large general use, and I'd recommend to have it in handy anyway).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. It appears that I need to install apt-file. Is there a way I could achieve the same results without installing apt-file?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: updated answer with mention of `dpkg -S`.

Comment: Thanks. I did however notice that there is no auto complete feature. Is there a reason why that is?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: It can't preemptively know what you want to search for, and it's more of a search utility for generic terms than anything else (just like `grep`/`sed`/`find` does not auto-complete the search terms). At least I guess that is how the reasoning went during the design of the tool.

Comment: Thanks Daniel however should it preemptively know if I have entered a partial name e.g. wnck